# Consistent Unity Error: Stopped polling job due to exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

So I keep on receiving this error whenever I load a scene or press play in my Unity Editor. I am using 2021.3.20f1

Stopped polling job due to exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at GooglePlayServices.UnityCompat.VersionFromAndroidSDKVersionsEnum (System.String enumName, System.String fallbackPrefKey, System.Int32 fallbackValue) [0x00001] in <48abf529805a49c69e88ffb3f8b573e9>:0

I just have no Idea where to go next

I began getting errors when attempting to build a bundle to upload to the Google Play Store. I need to internally test my project and I wanted to get to the point where I could upload an internal build to the store, acccesioble only by me and my tester. Google Play Console dashboard threw some errors my way, so I saught help. I was ultimately advised to upgrade from Unity 2019 to 2021 LTS, so I did that. And now that I've done this, I reveive the errors. This is my first attempt to put a game on the Play Store and so far I keep hitting hurdle and hurdle, each one seemingly more insurmountable than the next :(

Answer (score 0):

for myself, I found the following solution:

1. set minimum API Level -> 31
2. set Target API Level -> Automatic

It resolve error for me.